# Linux distributions for ARM processors

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, arm

Are there any Linux distributions (Other than Backtrack and Android) available for ARM processors?
specifically ARM 11 (SE Xperia X8)

Answer (score 9):

The ARM website has a page on [Linux Support for the ARM Architecture](http://arm.com/community/software-enablement/linux.php). It includes this list:

> Additionally, ARM works with the open source community and Linux distributions as well as commercial Linux partners including:
>
> - [Canonical](http://www.canonical.com) ([Ubuntu on ARM](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/arm))
> - [Debian](http://www.debian.org/ports/arm)
> - [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM#Fedora_ARM)
> - [Linaro](http://www.linaro.org)
> - [Maemo](http://maemo.org)
> - [MeeGo](http://meego.com)
> - [Movial](http://www.movial.com)
> - [Thundersoft](http://www.thunderst.com)
> - [ArchLinuxArm](http://archlinuxarm.org)

Answer (score 5):

You can find a list of systems that run on ARM processors [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Operating_systems). There are 23 Linux distributions and a few other Unix-like systems.

But many of them are not intended to run on mobiles, so after installation (if you manage to install it) you may encounter many problems like lack of drivers for almost everything (touchscreen, modem, wifi, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**[Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-arm.xml)**, which can give you significant speed and customization benefits, highly desired for an embedded/thin 
platform.

Answer (score 0):

ALTLinux community has been working on an ARM port of ALTLinux (and the Sisyphus package repository) ([description in Russian](http://www.altlinux.org/Ports/arm)): ARMv5 variant, and ARMv7 (hard-float).

ALTLinux infrastructure for building packages is convenient for such a task, because ALTLinux Team has taken care of constantly checking that the Sisyphus package repository can be correctly rebuilt automatically.